# Time spent with custom module

Tags: 7, forms

Can anyone help me with this, I want  to activate time spent module on my custom form module, and store the time spent on a field on my form. I think  that I could do it on the file `timespent.module` here.

```
function time_spent_init() {
  //if user has a role who is going to be tracked, add javascript code
  if (time_spent_user_has_role()) {
    $timer = variable_get('time_spent_timer', TIME_SPENT_TIMER);
    $limit = variable_get('time_spent_limit', TIME_SPENT_LIMIT);
    $mynide = -1; //false value
    //checks if this is a node page. taxonomy or views pages won't be counted.
    //confirm if this node type and user role will be tracked
    $nodetypes = variable_get('time_spent_node_types', 'all');
    if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
      if (($nodetypes == 'all' || $nodetypes[$node->type] === $node->type )) {
        $mynide = $node->nid;
      }
    }
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'time_spent') . '/time_spent.js');
    drupal_add_js(array('time_spent' => array('timer' => check_plain($timer), 'limit' => check_plain($limit), 'nid' => $mynide, 'sectoken' => drupal_get_token())), 'setting');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone, I found how to do it.

I have a custom module to create a form and I want to make "timespent" work and track user time spend on this page.

I use URL to get it work.

```
$nodetypes = variable_get('time_spent_node_types', 'all');
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  if (($nodetypes == 'all' || $nodetypes[$node->type] === $node->type )) {
    $mynide = $node->nid;
  }
}
```

This code searches the id of the node, for my purposes I replace this like that

```
if (arg(0) == 'module' && arg(1) == 'form') {
  $mynide = arg(3); // for me arg(3) is the nid i want to track
}
```